# How to program a reusable function with parameters in PHP that is declared in one file, and called from others?

Tags: php, html, function, parameters

I have a website with multiple pages.

I have this function which, for a given set of data, spits out an HTML table.

Currently, I have this code in three separate files, or pages, if you will, and all code is exactly replicated among the three.

I am looking for a way to have this code set reduced to just one instance so I can call it from any page/file, and only have to change one set of code.

**Hoping to find a way to declare this function in one file, which takes a parameter of the data set, and then call this function from my three separate files.  Is there a efficient way to do this using only PHP and HTML?**

For example, the function could be stored in FUNC.php, and called HandleThis(dataSetObj).
This function would then be called from Page1.php , Page2.php and Page3.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)/[`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

File **Func.php**:

```
function HandleThis($dataSetObj) {
    //.. function body
}
```

File **Page1.php**: (Similar in Page2, Page3)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/Func.php';

$value = HandleThis($parameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `include` / `include_once`

```
include 'functions.php';

$return = your_function($param);//you can do what ever you want
echo $return;
```

Here is the link for more detail http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php